# How do I install lxml in Pycharm?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, pycharm, lxml

I am relatively new to Python. I am trying to use BeautifulSoup to scrape websites and want to run the code:

```
source = requests.get(URLHERE).text
article = BeautifulSoup(source, "lxml")
```

Running the code returns the error message:

> bs4.FeatureNotFound: Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: lxml. Do you need to install a parser library?

I try to install the package in settings > project interpreter and get the error message

> error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/

My Microsoft Visual is up-to-date, and I've re-downloaded it multiple times to make sure. When I run *pip install lxml* in command prompt, I get:

> Requirement already satisfied: lxml in C:\users...

I can't figure out what to do. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is `lxml` presented at `File - Settings - Project - Python Interpreter`?

Answer (score 0):

I have a solid recommendation for you to use both for this problem and possible future problems. Have you ever tried using **Anaconda Navigator**?  It is a GUI that manages many packages, applications and enviroments with or without using command-line commands. You can create an eviroment of your desire and launch PyCharm from there. Since Anaconda has many features, i am pretty sure that you wont come across any problem such as yours. You can easily use the Anaconda Prompt to install , observe, search and manage every package for your enviroment and you can use the packages across any compiler or development platforms you have installed in your anaconda navigator. For more info on managing packages, I would strongly recommend this link [How to manage packages](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-pkgs.html) . I wish you good luck and I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In *pycharm* , go ot the **python package** section where you can see the installed packages .There you have to type the required library in the **search** part ,then simply click **install** .

I hope it will help you.